# how to resolve rendering error as shown here?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

```
In file included from /usr/include/gazebo-1.6/gazebo/rendering/Conversions.hh:20:0,
                 from /usr/include/gazebo-1.6/gazebo/rendering/rendering.hh:8,
                 from /home/udayraj/.gazebo/models/my_robot/gazebo_plugin_tutorial/model_push.cc:6:
/usr/include/gazebo-1.6/gazebo/rendering/ogre_gazebo.h:22:18: fatal error: Ogre.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/model_push.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2392/how-to-resolve-rendering-error-as-shown-here?/) by [ramaashare](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/288/ramaashare/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

it may be that OGRE is not installed, or the paths are not set properly, take a look at [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1125/after-updating-gazebo-to-13-under-groovy-i-get-an/) similar problem see if that fixes it, if not let us know, and maybe explain in more detail how you installed gazebo.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1